# Firefox on newly installed Ubuntu 20.10 does not stream videos

Tags: system-installation, firefox, video, 20.10, streaming

After a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.10, I was unable to stream video content through Firefox. Firefox showed blank screens or unhelpful messages.

Comment: "*unhelpful messages*" - the messages may have been unhelpful to you, but they are essential for documenting the problem, and essential for this Q&A to be helpful for future visitors. Please include them in your question.  My first guess on a new install is that you are trying to play DRM content and you didn't read/accept the notification from Firefox that tells you that you need the Widevine plugin

Answer (score 0):

Installing a video streaming program, VLC, recognized by Firefox, solved the problem.

Perhaps Ubuntu could include a Firefox friendly audio-visual streaming package in its installation image.